# AngularFirebase - Getting indexOf a node in firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database

So i have this array as shown below.

[monthlysalesarray log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWHGQ.png)


which i obtained from my firebase database as shown below

[firebase database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgld1.png)

Is there any way that i could use the value "September 2018" to get the index 1 of the array?
I tried using indexOf method but it returned -1.

Answer (score 0):

Use **findIndex** since you're dealing with an *array of objects*. indexOf only works on an array of primitive types (numbers, strings, boolean).

```
this.dataService.getIndex(monthString)
  .subscribe(
    (data) => {
      let index = data.findIndex((element) => {
        return element.month === "monthString"     //e.g. "September 2018"
      });
      //do something with index
    }
  );
```